# scp protected file from remote machine to local machine through terminal

Tags: permissions, ssh

So, I'm trying this:

```
ssh -t -e none host "sudo cat /location/to/some/file.txt" | xclip -selection c
```

With `-t` option, i'm supposed to get password prompt for `sudo`. But, I'm not. Without it, well permission denied.

What I'm getting for sudo prompt, with -t option, is a new line, where I tried entering the sudo password, but nothing happens and after a little while it drops saying `Connection to host closed`.

Is there any other way (using terminal only) around to copy a protected file from a remote machine to local.

EDIT:

@Félicien is right. The `ssh` is masked because of the pipe `|`. The password-asking-prompt will also go through the pipe and change the input of `xclip`

Comment: Does your ssh server forbid root login ? if no, you can connect directly as root `ssh -e none root@host "cat /location/to/some/file.txt" | xclip -selection c`

Comment: yes it does, it does forbid root login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the @Félicien's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1010248/566421) provides the reason of the issue, I found workaround how to solve it by using intermediate temp file and the command `tee`:

```
ssh -t -e none -i /path/to/id_rsa user@host "sudo cat /location/to/some/file.txt" | \
    tee /tmp/xclip.txt && \
    sed '1d' /tmp/xclip.txt | \
    xclip -selection c
```

- The output of the `ssh` command will be piped to the command `tee` that will write it into a new file within `/tmp`.
- Then the command `sed '1d'` will output the content of the new file without the first line that is `[sudo] password for <user>:` and finally this output ill be piped to `xclip`.
- You can create a custom command by adding a function in your `.bashrc` to make the tings more simple in the future.

Comment: Isn't `tail -2 <file>` to print only the 2 last lines of the file?

Comment: I would have used `tail -n +2` to ignore the first line

Comment: @Félicien, you are right! I've changed `tail` with `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

From what I tested, the `-t` option is working, but is masked because of the pipe 
`|` in the command. The terminal is waiting for you to put the password but you cannot see it.

You can put your password when the terminal seems to "wait", but the risk is that the password-asking-prompt will also go through the pipe and change the input of `xclip`

Comment: What I'm getting for sudo prompt, with -t option, is a new line, where I tried entering the sudo password, but nothing happens and after a little while it drops saying `Connection to host closed`

Comment: yes, you're right. I removed the `|` and it's working fine. But now how do I copy